# CMake is not found when running through make

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, msys

I'm trying to build https://github.com/AlbertWerner/cryptonotecoinwallet and facing an issue.

According to the README of the repo, I can run `cmake` command and it completes without any errors. But then, when I run `make`, it gives me the below error.

```
$ make
make: /usr/bin/cmake: Command not found
make: *** [Makefile:5138: cmake_check_build_system] Error 127
```

I'm using MSYS on Windows and here are the corresponding details.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/opt/bin:/c/Windows/System32:/c/Windows:/c/Windows/System32/Wbem:/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/usr/bin/site_perl:/usr/bin/vendor_perl:/usr/bin/core_perl:/mingw32/bin

$ which cmake
/mingw32/bin/cmake
```

Seems like it's looking for `cmake` in the wrong path.

Makefile

```
cmake_check_build_system:
    $(CMAKE_COMMAND) -H$(CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR) -B$(CMAKE_BINARY_DIR) --check-build-system CMakeFiles/Makefile.cmake 0
.PHONY : cmake_check_build_system # <== Line 5139
```

I'm not sure what's wrong. Please help me out.

Thanks.

Comment: It seems that when `cmake` has been run, its path was actually `/usr/bin/cmake`. From which environment (Windows, MSYS) you have run `cmake` and which [generator](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/manual/cmake-generators.7.html) you have used?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that you launch MSYS2 using the `mingw32.exe` executable at the top level of your MSYS2 installation, and that you use that environment when you first run `cmake`.  If you ran CMake in a different environment, remove all the files it created.  The commands for running `cmake` and building the project should be something like this, assuming the developers have set it up in a reasonable way:

```
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -G"MSYS Makefiles"
make
```

I didn't try this myself because I am wary of running random code from the internet, but I found this note in the CMakefile indicating that the developers do not support MSYS2:

```
if (WIN32)
  if (NOT MSVC)
        message(FATAL_ERROR "Only MSVC is supported on this platform")
  endif ()
  ...
```

So you will have to spend some effort on porting the Windows-specific code in this program to GCC if you really want to do this.