# Failed to find "glu32" in "" with CMAKE_CXX_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE ""

Tags: c++, cmake, glu

I'm trying to compile [cryptonotecoinwallet](https://github.com/AlbertWerner/cryptonotecoinwallet) repo using CMake with VS2010 compiler (according to the comments I got for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547690/cmake-is-not-found-when-running-through-make/48548300#48548300))

[image: CMake Error]

I tried to add the below line to the CMake file and the cache file, but no luck.

```
set (CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.1\\Lib\\x64")
```

I tried to compile it using the command line, but got the same error.

```
D:\My Documents\Fiverr\C++ and Qt\FitsoCoin\cryptonotewallet>cmake.exe -DBOOST_ROOT=C:\\boost_1_66_0 -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR=C:\\boost_1_66_0\\lib32-msvc-1
0.0:C:\\boost_1_66_0\\libs  -G "Visual Studio 10 2010" .
CMake Error at C:/Qt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/msvc2010_opengl/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:16 (message):
  Failed to find "glu32" in "" with CMAKE_CXX_LIBRARY_ARCHITECTURE "".
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  C:/Qt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/msvc2010_opengl/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfigExtras.cmake:52 (_qt5gui_find_extra_libs)
  C:/Qt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/msvc2010_opengl/lib/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake:152 (include)
  CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package)
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks.

Comment: Generator [Visual Studio 10 2010](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/generator/Visual%20Studio%2010%202010.html) is 32-bit programs. So, a library from `x64` subfolder isn't suited for it. For 64-bit programs use `Visual Studio 10 2010 Win64` as generator name.

Comment: I changed the lib path to `"C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\\Windows\\v7.1\\Lib"` but it's still the same.

Comment: What is exact location of `glu32` library on your system? And which exact name of the library file?

Comment: The lib resides inside ``C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\x64``. The name is `GlU32.Lib`

Comment: Try to set *CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH* variable to the directory with this library: `set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1\Lib\x64")`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev : This works! Please make this the answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to point CMake (and `Find*` scripts) to directory with a libraries, set [CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH.html) variable:

```
set(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH "C:/Program Files/Microsoft SDKs/Windows/v7.1/Lib/x64")
```

---

Variable [CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/variable/CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH.html), which you are trying to set, is expected to point to *installation prefix*. This prefix is used when search a library, but only with subdirectories like `lib/` appended to it.