# make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 127

Tags: ubuntu, cmake

I have a computer installed with Ubuntu 18.04.

I tried to use the command "make" for the star-engine.
https://gitlab.com/meso-star/star-engine

However, the following errors pop up:

```
make: /snap/cmake/283/bin/cmake: Command not found
Makefile:384: recipe for target 'cmake_check_build_system' failed
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 127
```

I tried removing "cmake" and install it again. But the problem persists.

I think the problem is due to unknown changes to the computer by ubuntu's updates during these 2 weeks.

Thank you very much

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Did you run through the other [build steps](https://gitlab.com/meso-star/star-engine#build) for this repository? Such as `cmake ../cmake`? You may have to clean whatever old/cached files you have in `star-engine/build`, and re-configure and rebuild everything.

Comment: Yes, I did. The cmake worked well 2 weeks ago. But the abovementioned problems pop up today when I try using "make"

Comment: So did you *delete* the Makefile, and regenerate it by running the `cmake` command in the instructions?

Comment: I cannot use the command "make clean", same errors pop up. I tried deleting Makefile,, but the following errors pop up make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found. Stop.

Comment: So you deleted the Makefile, re-ran this command `cmake ../cmake && make`, and still received errors?

Comment: This is the error if I do the cmmand "make clean" make[2]: /snap/cmake/283/bin/cmake: Command not found
CMakeFiles/star-engine-profile.dir/build.make:75: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/star-engine-profile.dir/clean' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/star-engine-profile.dir/clean] Error 127
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:146: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/star-engine-profile.dir/clean' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/star-engine-profile.dir/clean] Error 2
Makefile:90: recipe for target 'clean' failed
make: *** [clean] Error 2

Comment: Running `make clean` does **not** delete the Makefile. You need to manually delete the Makefile. Also, it is important to run the CMake command *before* running `make`, because CMake **regenerates** the Makefile.

Comment: Thank you very much. I can now run star-engine. But I have another problem that is I have a foler pt/build , I tried to run ```make``` and the following error pop up ```CMakeFiles/pt.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/pt.dir/home/kenchung/pt_ken/src/pt.c.o' failed
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/pt.dir/home/kenchung/pt_ken/src/pt.c.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:67: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/pt.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/pt.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:83: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2```

Comment: This Q&A appears to be the same issue mentioned in your question post. [CMake is not found when running through make](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48547690/cmake-is-not-found-when-running-through-make)